# IE not liking URL variable?

Tags: javascript, url

Hey guys, I have this quite simple script which works great on chrome & firefox. 
The idea is to nab "choice" value from the URL and proceed with the script. As mentioned other browsers work fine, but IE seems to have trouble with it.

Does anyone know a workaround? I don't want to just run the function on the previous page.

```
var url1 = "https://www.youtube.com";
var url2 = "http://ign.com";



function jukebox()

{

let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
let choice = params.get("choice");


      if ( choice == 1 )
     {        

               window.location=(url1);   

     }

       else if ( choice == 2 ) 
            {


               window.location=(url2);

            }

} 


jukebox();
redirect();
```

Comment: You should properly indent your code.

Comment: Why not `window.location=url1`?

Comment: What version of IE and what error message do you get, if any?

Comment: The URL API is not supported by IE: http://caniuse.com/#feat=url

Comment: no error, just blank page. It doesn't get past let params, if I use Document write on the urls before I can see them in the browser.

PS I tried removing ('') and it doesn't help, thanks

Comment: @EelisEwert You can't use `new URL` in IE.

Comment: Another good place to check if a function is supported on your browser is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

Answer (score 1):

IE does not support searchParams but you could try writing your own parse function:

```
var params = {};
var str = document.location;
var start = str.indexOf("?");
document.write(start+"<br>")
start += str.slice(start).indexOf("choice=") + 7;
var end = start + str.slice(start).indexOf("&") + 1;
if (!end) end = str.length 
var choice = str.slice(start, end);
```